# nodejs mmsql bulk insert to temp table

Tags: sql-server, node.js, node-mssql

I'm using mssql to connect to sql server 2012 with node.js. I've discovered the bulk insert option in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#bulk)

I'm wanting to insert data into a temporary table, which the doc says I can do. Here is what I'm trying:

```
createConnection(config.dbConfig);
    var table = new sql.Table('#atable');
    table.create = true;
    table.columns.add('a', sql.Int, { nullable: false});
    table.rows.add(1);
    table.rows.add(2);
    table.rows.add(3);
    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.bulk(table, function(err, rowCount){
       if(err){
           console.log('bulk insert error');
           console.log(err);
       } 
        var taco = new sql.Request();
        taco.query('select * from #atable', function(err, recordset){
           if(err){
               console.log('taco error:' + err);
           } 
           console.log('taco recordset:');
           console.log(recordset);
        });
    });
```

I get this output:

> taco error:RequestError: Invalid object name '#atable'.

If I remove the hash then it creates a real table on the server. I can't find any examples actually using a temporary table. I'd like to know how to do this. If not, then I'll have to take another approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched over to a regular sql statement to create a temporary table, and then tried to query it. What I realized was the `new sql.Request` was most of my problem. The temporary table doesn't exist on another connection/request/thread.

So this was my solution:

```
var table = new sql.Table('#atable');
    table.create = true;
    table.columns.add('a', sql.Int, { nullable: false});
    table.rows.add(1);
    table.rows.add(2);
    table.rows.add(3);
    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.bulk(table, function(err, rowCount){
       if(err){
           console.log('bulk insert error');
           console.log(err);
           return;
       } 

        request.query('select * from #atable', function(err, recordset){
       if(err){
           console.log('taco error:' + err);
           return;
       } 
       console.log('taco recordset:');
       console.log(recordset);
    });
    });
```

It's a subtle change. Inside the request.bulk call I used the same request object (smartly named request) to query the table. I wasn't creating a new connection object so I didn't realize I was using a connection where the table didn't exist.